# Filter an array before pushing the items in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection in mongo that is called "activities". Each activity has `users` field that is an array of objects that includes the `userId` and a `scores` object. I have another list of user Ids. I want to add to the `users` field only users from the list that are not already exist in the `users` array with default `scores` value so I will not override the `scores` of existing users.

Let's say the activity has this `users` array:

```
[{ userId: 1, scores: { failures: 2, wins: 4 } }, 
 { userId: 2, scores: { failures: 0, wins: 2 } }]
```

and userIds array is [2, 3] and default scores are `{ failures: 0, wins: 0 }` the result should be

```
[{ userId: 1, scores: { failures: 2, wins: 4 } }, 
 { userId: 2, scores: { failures: 0, wins: 2 } }, 
 { userId: 3, scores: { failures: 0, wins: 0 } }]
```

Only userId 3 should be added with the default `scores` because userId 2 already exists.

Comment: Can you post your current implementation if possible?

Comment: @lpizzinidev I tried to user arrayFilters but I didn't know how to reference to the existing and added users arrays. I tried something like this: db.activities.updateOne({ _id: <activityId> },   { $addToSet: { users: { $each: <newUsers> } } },   { arrayFilters: [ { "user.userId": { $not: { $in: <existingUserIds> } } } ] } )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pipelined update and $reduce,

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "users": {
        $reduce: {
          input: [2,3],                             //1. your input
          initialValue: "$users",                   //2. start with existing users array field
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $in: ["$$this","$$value.userId"]    //3. if each input exists in users array
              },
              {
                $concatArrays: ["$$value"]          //4. retain existing users array
              },
              {
                $concatArrays: [                    //5. if not, concatenate new element to array
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    {
                      userId: "$$this",
                      scores: {
                        failures: 0,
                        wins: 0
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XujTRFfNJK8)